# Interrupting a chain of events in javascript

Tags: javascript

This small JavaScript page contains `A` tags, which can either be clicked or reached by use of the left and right arrows. The same function should be called in both cases. The current solution is to focus() on left or right arrow, and to call the same function **onmousedown** and **onfocus** :

```
function tab(e) {     //incomplete, just for illustration purposes
  var as = document.getElementById("areas");
  if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) {
  as.firstChild.focus();
  ...
}

...
a.onmousedown = mousedown;
a.onfocus = mousedown;
```

This has the inconvenient that clicking a A tag will also focus it, and the function will be called twice.

```
function mousedown(e) {
  if (Date.now() - lastEvent < 100) {
    return;                                       
  }
  else {
    lastEvent = Date.now();
  }
  ...
```

This is the current solution : remembering the milliseconds from epoch of a mousedown() call, and if another call arrives less than 100ms later, it has to be a succession of onmousedown and onfocus during the same user click.

Is there a better solution? `e.cancelbubble = true;` won't work, as this is two different events. Is there some way to stop the whole event chain? I feel that a one-liner would be way more elegant than this time-remembering hack.

Thank you.

Comment: *"`e.cancelbubble = true;` won't work, as this is two different events."* And it's IE-only anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution is probably best. In engineering, this is called "debouncing" the input (the term comes from the "[bouncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce)" [electrical and mechanical] of the contacts of physical switches when they're pressed).

Preventing the default action of the `mousedown` event *might* prevent the `focus` event, but I think it would be likely to have unpleasant side-effects, whereas your current solution is nicely contained.